# ERROR encountered only below iOS 17 devices "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, exception

I've just updated my XCode to version 15, and I encountered this error (only iOS versions below 17)

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

code that shows this error (PathMonitorConectivityProvider.swift):

When I ran my code from XCode (the iOS device version is iOS 16.4), an exception occurred in the below code.

```
import Foundation
import Network

@available(iOS 12, *)
public class PathMonitorConnectivityProvider: NSObject, ConnectivityProvider {

  private let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

  private var _pathMonitor: NWPathMonitor?

  public var currentConnectivityType: ConnectivityType {
    let path = ensurePathMonitor().currentPath
    // .satisfied means that the network is available
    if path.status == .satisfied {
      if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
        return .wifi
      } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
        return .cellular
      } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wiredEthernet) {
        // .wiredEthernet is available in simulator
        // but for consistency it is probably correct to report .wifi
        return .wifi
      } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.other) {
        return .other
      }
    }
    return .none
  }

  public var connectivityUpdateHandler: ConnectivityUpdateHandler?

  override init() {
    super.init()
    _ = ensurePathMonitor()
  }

  public func start() {
    _ = ensurePathMonitor()
  }

  public func stop() {
    _pathMonitor?.cancel()
    _pathMonitor = nil
  }

  @discardableResult
  private func ensurePathMonitor() -> NWPathMonitor {
    if (_pathMonitor == nil) {
      let pathMonitor = NWPathMonitor()
      pathMonitor.start(queue: queue)
      pathMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = pathUpdateHandler
      _pathMonitor = pathMonitor
    }
    return _pathMonitor!
  }

  private func pathUpdateHandler(path: NWPath) {
    connectivityUpdateHandler?(currentConnectivityType)
  }
}
```

[Screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eruJR.png)

Additionally Flutter doctor results:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-x64, locale en-LK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Additionally AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB0SHZK3ngwOu0r26fm3pOrhKumXS7XdHY")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same error. I installed xCode 15 today and my flutter project is crashing at the same line of code. Probably we should rise a flag on the Issues section for Connectivity_Plus library from GitHub:
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/labels/connectivity_plus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is to upgrade all your libraries on the Pods project, inclusive `Flutter` from `IOS Deployment Target 11.0` to version `12.0` or higher.
For some reasons XCode 15 will downgrade all the versions to 9.0 or 11.0 which will cause chaos in your project and strange errors like this.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same issue in Xcode 15, and indeed, changing the **iOS Deployment Target** from 11.0 to 12.0 resolved it for me. However, it's not necessary to do this manually for every package - you can simply add the script to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
 project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
   end
 end
end
```

To update your Pods, use this commands in the ios folder of your project:

```
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
rm -f Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
```

PS Be ready to change it again next year to 13.0 when we get Xcode 16 and iOS 18 =)

Comment: Thank you!
This did the trick after finding out that manually changing them kept getting cleared (during a build I guess)... and I guess because the Podfile had this line maybe that was overriding my manual changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you too, but I had the exact same error (using XCode 15) and I solved it by ensuring that the "iOS Deployment Target" for every one of my dependencies, in "Pods" tab (see screenshot), matched the one I declared in my "Runner" tab.

Namely, in Runner I had set "iOS Deployment Target" to iOS 12, but in my dependencies in Pods it was iOS 11.

Updated everything to iOS 12 and it worked.

Hope it helps, I'm not in a position to offer more expertise, I'm completely unfamiliar with iOS development

Screenshot:
[image: Changed those to iOS 12, to match the version I had in my Runner]

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks so much, but with this fix other functionality will break or not i am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

XCode 15 here, **I had similar error** and what I figured out is to change minimum deployment target to higher version than IOS 11.x in **TARGET'S RUNNER** (I've changed to iOS 13.0), changing each library separately didn't work for me, probably because Xcode downgrades those libs to lower version while building app (idk why this is working that way).

[image]