# Flutter app is crashing in production due to a segmentation

Tags: ios, flutter, segmentation-fault

When i download my App from my device it works. If I open it in Testflight its works. If someone else tries to start the App, it crashes instantly.

The App runs in Flutter without any problems.

Here are the logs :

Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Incident Identifier: F0394EE0-06DD-4578-B4B0-A7F25C90EF84

CrashReporter Key: 099D1046-1E88-E852-6DC3-88AB0A1D35F9

Hardware Model: Macmini9,1

Process: Runner [50409]

Path: /private/var/folders/*/Runner.app/Runner

Identifier: QuizAPP3D

Version: 1.21 (1.21)

AppStoreTools: 15A240a

AppVariant: 1:MacFamily20,1:15

Code Type: ARM-64 (Native)

Role: Foreground

Parent Process: launchd [1]

Coalition: QuizAPP3D [26171]

Date/Time: 2023-10-04 18:59:22.9700 +0200

Launch Time: 2023-10-04 18:59:22.7492 +0200

OS Version: macOS 13.6 (22G120)

Release Type: User

Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000

Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region. Bytes before following region: 4297162752

REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL

### UNUSED SPACE AT START

__TEXT                      100218000-100220000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...er.app/Runner
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11

Terminating Process: exc handler [50409]

Triggered by Thread: 0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0 ??? 0x0 ???

1 connectivity_plus 0x1009c8a60 @objc PathMonitorConnectivityProvider.init() + 20

2 connectivity_plus 0x1009ca334 PathMonitorConnectivityProvider.__allocating_init() + 24 [inlined]

3 connectivity_plus 0x1009ca334 specialized static SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.register(with:) + 308 (SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.swift:28)

4 connectivity_plus 0x1009c9844 static SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.register(with:) + 8 [inlined]

5 connectivity_plus 0x1009c9844 @objc static SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.register(with:) + 32 (:17)

6 Runner 0x100220048 0x100218000 + 32840

7 Runner 0x1002203ac 0x100218000 + 33708

8 UIKitCore 0x1bab6e1c4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 296

9 UIKitCore 0x1bab6d690 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2820

10 UIKitCore 0x1bab6b960 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 988

11 UIKitCore 0x1bab6b494 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 108

12 UIKitCore 0x1bab68064 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112

13 UIKitCore 0x1bab6ade0 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216

14 UIKitCore 0x1bab6ab64 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 332

15 UIKitCore 0x1bab6a0fc -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 624

16 UIKitCore 0x1bab69de8 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 252

17 UIKitCore 0x1bab68640 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148

18 UIKitCore 0x1bb2b1688 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736

19 UIKitCore 0x1bb388b54 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224

20 UIKitCore 0x1bab681ec -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316

21 UIKitCore 0x1badc9b0c __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.240 + 556

22 UIKitCore 0x1bab67688 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216

23 UIKitCore 0x1bab674f8 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244

24 UIKitCore 0x1bab5d730 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 520

25 UIKitCore 0x1bab5d4b0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288

26 FrontBoardServices 0x1a3796114 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 372

27 FrontBoardServices 0x1a37b9a88 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.102 + 120

28 FrontBoardServices 0x1a3784d30 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 196

29 FrontBoardServices 0x1a37b96bc __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 356

30 libdispatch.dylib 0x18f108400 _dispatch_client_callout + 20

31 libdispatch.dylib 0x18f10be70 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264

32 FrontBoardServices 0x1a3784c44 FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK + 48

33 FrontBoardServices 0x1a37d40b8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220

34 FrontBoardServices 0x1a3784be4 -[FBSSerialQueue _p

Works fine on development & Testflight

Answer (score 1):

(I mistakenly answered this before realizing that this was asked before on StackOverflow, and seemingly [answered by the person whose bug I linked below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77147216/error-encountered-only-below-ios-17-devices-thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-a).)

---

According to issue [fluttercommunity/plus_plugins#2154](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2154), this `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` failure seems to be a recent bug (filed September 2023, two weeks ago) associated with Xcode 15 and its minimum iOS deployment settings.

Bug reporter [florentin89](https://github.com/florentin89) graciously offered a [workaround](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2154#issuecomment-1729744761) (screenshot in linked post):

> The solution in my case was to upgrade all the libraries inclusive `Flutter` from IOS Deployment Target 9.0 or 11.0 to version 12.0 or higher.
> For some reason Xcode 15 will change the version for all libraries(pods) from 12.0 or above to a range between 9.0 and 11.0, causing a lot of chaos in your project and weird errors.

Based on the emoji reactions, that post seemed to get positive attention; a [follow-up by user jkgatt](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/2154#issuecomment-1730330223) offered a `post_install` script to automate the setting.

(For what it's worth, I got to this by searching PathMonitorConnectivityProvider on Google; the GitHub link came up quickly for me.)